# pthread mutex does not work correctly on macOS

Tags: c, linux, macos, pthreads, mutex

Currently I am learning POSIX threads on Linux. The following example is counting how many 3(int) there are in an integer array, which returns a correct answer on CentOS 6.5 but a wrong one on macOS 10.12.4.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define thread_num 16
#define MB 1024 * 1024
int *array;
int length; //array length
int count;
int t; //number of thread
void *count3s_thread(void* id);

pthread_mutex_t myMutex;//create a mutex

int main()
{
    //initialize mutex
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL) != 0)
        printf("Mutex init failed!\n");
    int i;
    int tid[thread_num];
    pthread_t threads[thread_num];
    length = 64 * MB;
    array = malloc(length * 4);

    //initialize the array
    //when i is an odd number, array[i] = 4
    //when i is an even number, array[i] = 3
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        array[i] = i % 2 ? 4 : 3;

    for (t = 0; t < thread_num; t++)
    {
        count = 0;
        tid[t]=t;
        int err = pthread_create(&(threads[t]), NULL, count3s_thread,&(tid[t]) );
        if (err)
        {
            printf("create thread error!\n");
            return 0;           
        }
    }
    for (t = 1; t < thread_num; t++)
        pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    printf("Total count= %d \n",count);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex);

    return 0;
}

void *count3s_thread(void* id)
{
    //printf("id from count3s_thread = %d\n", *(int *)id);
    int length_per_thread = length / thread_num; //length of every thread
    int start = *(int *)id * length_per_thread;
    int i;
    for (i = start; i < start + length_per_thread; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == 3)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
            count++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The answer should be 64 * 1024 * 1024 / 2 = 67,108,864 / 2 = 33,554,432. But the answer on macOS is never right. I compile the code with the following options:

```
gcc mutex-demo.c -lpthread -o mutex-demo
```

I have tried solving the problem following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936019/pthread-mutex-not-working-correctly). However, I still got a wrong answer having initialized pthread mutex. Did I miss something?

PS: I have tried either `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` or `pthread_mutex_init( &mutex, NULL)` but the program running on macOS still returns a wrong answer.

Advanced thanks!

Comment: The `for` loop for `pthread_join` starts at `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: Did you get the correct value if you call the function without `pthread_create`? I do not get your expected value: http://ideone.com/z3Ne2a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `count = 0;` before the `pthread_create` sets `count` to `0`, so you reset the value of `count` while the threads increment them. Remove this line. It probably worked on other systems, when the main thread finishes the `pthread_create` before the threads starts counting.

I already mentioned it in the comments:

```
for (t = 1; t < thread_num; t++)
    pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
```

should be

```
for (t = 0; t < thread_num; t++)
     //  ^
    pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
```

otherwise you will not wait for the first thread to be done.

Comment: Thanks! After I remove line `count = 0;` and set `t = 0` in the pthread_join loop, the result is finally right. However, I have one more question: why does `pthread_create` automatically set `count` to `0`? Neither function `pthread_create` nor `count3s_thread` has the statement which can set `count` to `0`.

Comment: `count` is a global variable, which are `0` initialized.

Comment: Oh, I just forgot global variables in C will be automatically initialized to `0`. Anyway, thank you for telling me so much.