# Pthreads: Unable to put my print statement outside of my mutex and run successfully. Is there any way to effect this?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

In short, this code has 4 threads competing for pearls in a cave. They are supposed to take pearls out of the cave, one at a time only, and stop when the cave runs out.

My code runs great when I have my printf() within the mutex, but when I take it out, I get wrong printout data (although the final value is correct after the code finishes).

I created a structure specific to each thread's ID (so there would be no race conditions there) so I could update after each thread executes and access data in the printf() that way. The data in this structure is correct, but it's how it is accessed in the printf statement that is causing the problem. The printf() statement uses my_rank to print the correct data. When I move this printf() out of the lock, the runtime info is wrong, because (somehow) thread B goes in twice and prints the same data twice.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NUM_PIRATE_THREADS 4 /* number of pirate threads to run */
#define OPEN_SESAME 0 /* single bit value representation of password */
#define OPEN_WATERMELON 1 /* single bit value representation of password */
#define SLEEP_TIME 2 /* time for thread to sleep after execution */

/* percent value for "open, sesame" */
const double OPEN_SESAME_PERCENTAGE = 0.10;

/* percent value for "open, watermelon" */
const double OPEN_WATERMELON_PERCENTAGE = 0.15;

struct PirateBag {
    char alphaForPirate;
    double caveTotal;
    double currentPearlsToTake;
    double takePercentage;
};

/* pirate thread function */
void *pirate(void* rank);

/* pirate thread pearl removal and update function */
double executeRemoval(int *piratesBooty, struct PirateBag *piratesBag,
                      const long pirate_rank, const double cavePearls);

/* total number of items in resource (pearls in the cave) */
static double cavePearls = 1000.00;

/* mutual exlusion lock; mutual exclusion considered in this version */
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

/* array of pirate threads */
static pthread_t *thread_handles;

/* array to store the number of pearls garnered by each pirate */
int piratesBooty[NUM_PIRATE_THREADS];

/* array to store current pearls being retrieved from cave by pirate thread */
struct PirateBag piratesBag[NUM_PIRATE_THREADS];

/* main function */
int main() {

    /* alert user pirate threads are about to begin consuming pearls */
    printf("\nAvast matey, we are a'comin' fer yee pearls!!\n\n");

    /* index variable for pirate threads */
    long threadIndex;

    /* char variable for pirate thread labeling (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ...) */
    char alphaForPirate = 'A';

    /* create and allocate memory for thread_handles array */
    thread_handles = (pthread_t*)malloc(NUM_PIRATE_THREADS*sizeof(pthread_t));

    /* create and run pirate threads...YAR!*/
    for (threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < NUM_PIRATE_THREADS; ++threadIndex) {
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[threadIndex], NULL,
                       pirate, (void*)threadIndex);
    }

    /* join pirate threads...AVAST MATEY!*/
    for (threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < NUM_PIRATE_THREADS; ++threadIndex) {
        pthread_join(thread_handles[threadIndex], NULL);
    }

    /* update your final cave pearl number to a whole integer value */
    cavePearls = ceil(cavePearls);

    /* display pearl data after pirate thread execution */
    printf("\nYar!! The cave be empty!!\n\n");
    for (threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < NUM_PIRATE_THREADS; ++threadIndex){
        printf("Pirate %c got %d pearls\n",
               alphaForPirate, piratesBooty[threadIndex]);
        alphaForPirate++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* free memory */
    free(thread_handles);

    return 0;
} /* end of main() */

/* pirate thread function */
void *pirate(void* rank) {

    /* amount of pearls pirate thread may take during current entry to cave */
    double pearlsToGrab = 0;

    while(1) { /* continue execution while pearls remain in cave */

        /* identify which pirate thread you are currently executing */
        long my_rank = (long)rank;

        /* make pirate thread sleep for SLEEP_TIME seconds */
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

        /* cave has been emptied, pirate thread should stop */
        if (cavePearls < 1)
            return 0;

        /*****************************/
        /* CRITICAL SECTION LOCKED */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        /* remove the correct number of pearls from the cave */
        cavePearls -= executeRemoval(piratesBooty, piratesBag, my_rank, cavePearls);

        /* print pirate thread data for current entry into the cave */
        printf("Pirate %c gets %d of the pearls, %.f%% of %.0f pearls available in cave\n",
               piratesBag[my_rank].alphaForPirate, (int)piratesBag[my_rank].currentPearlsToTake,
               piratesBag[my_rank].takePercentage, piratesBag[my_rank].caveTotal);

        /* CRITICAL SECTION UNLOCKED */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        /*****************************/

    } /* end of while-loop */

    /* have pirate thread(s) terminate */
    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}

/* pirate thread pearl removal and collection update function */
double executeRemoval(int *piratesBooty, struct PirateBag *piratesBag, const long pirate_rank,
                      const double cavePearls) {

    /* cave has been emptied, pirate thread should stop */
    if (cavePearls < 1)
        return 0;

    /* variable to capture correct pirate thread percentage of pearls to take */
    double takePercentVal;

    /* identify correct pirate thread percentage */
    if (pirate_rank % 2 == OPEN_SESAME)
        takePercentVal = OPEN_SESAME_PERCENTAGE;
    else takePercentVal = OPEN_WATERMELON_PERCENTAGE;

    /* update data for pirate thread */
    piratesBooty[pirate_rank] += ceil(cavePearls * takePercentVal);
    piratesBag[pirate_rank].alphaForPirate = (pirate_rank + 'A');
    piratesBag[pirate_rank].caveTotal = cavePearls;
    piratesBag[pirate_rank].currentPearlsToTake = ceil(cavePearls * takePercentVal);
    piratesBag[pirate_rank].takePercentage = (takePercentVal * 100);

    /* return number of pearls pirate thread should take */
    return ceil(cavePearls * takePercentVal);
}
```

**Here is the runtime error I get when I move the printf() out of the lock:**

Pirate A gets 100 of the pearls, 10% of 1000 pearls available in cave

Pirate B gets 135 of the pearls, 15% of 900 pearls available in cave

Pirate B gets 135 of the pearls, 15% of 900 pearls available in cave

Pirate D gets 115 of the pearls, 15% of 765 pearls available in cave

Comment: Might be as simple as [initializing the mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936019/pthread-mutex-not-working-correctly). And checking `if (cavePearls < 1)` outside of the critical section is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Do you copy the values to be printed to local variables, and print the copies?

If you simply move the call to the `printf` function, you also move the reads of shared state out of the critical section.

Comment: At first, I had local variables and was doing everything outside of the critical section (only deducting the cave pearls). I ran into issues with the wrong data being printed out. The final data would be correct, but not the runtime. So, I decided I'd make an array of structs so only rank1 would go into cell 1, etc. Thought that would do it. Still wouldn't work 100% of the time.

Comment: I don't use local variables in the thread function. I created an array of structs in main, so thread 0 would only update cell 0, etc. Thought that would do the trick. No joy.